# SQL: variable name and number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I would like to execute a database search which returns all data, resulting in  one foo-data in one row.

I have 3 tables: *foo*, *bar* and *barbar*

*foo* is the main table. Multiple records from *bar* might have the same foreign key referring to the primary key of *foo* and zero or one record in *barbar* can have a foreign key referring to the primary key of *bar* for each record in *bar*.

My ideal SQL query looks like this, but doesn't work:

```
SELECT

foo.*,
barbar.text AS CONCAT('barbar_', barbar.barPK, '_text'),
bar.text AS CONCAT('bar_', bar.PK, '_text')

FROM

foo
LEFT JOIN bar ON foo.PK = bar.fooPK
LEFT JOIN barbar ON bar.PK = barbar.barPK

ORDER BY foo.PK LIMIT 0, 200
```

If only one bar/barbar combination exists the answer has foo-fields, bar.text and barbar.text. If multiple bar/barbar combinations referring to foo exist, I wish to return the foo-fields and both bar/barbar fields (bar.text and barbar.text) for each combination.

What would you say is the easiest way to select all Data (LIMITed to foo(0, 200))?

I hope it is possible in one query and I don't have to query again for each 200 records from *foo*.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but you cannot set the column name depending on the result rows. How would you even use a result like this, you don't even know the column names. And what name would the column have if you have two rows? The name from the first, or the name from the second row? All in all: It's might be an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#answer-66378). You might use a different approach. Maybe describe the original problem you are trying to solve with this idea, there are probably better ways to do it.

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem with the query considering the requirements. I agree that the dynamic column names can't work, but why do you need them?

Comment: I need dynamic names, because if multiple bar/barbar exist, they need different names. @Solarflare:I just need all data as simple as possible

Comment: Could you give a sample input and output that you want to get (including the column names), or probably 2 examples, so we can see the column name thing? I still don't know what you are trying to do.